# Jquery click event for attribute with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write for click event attribute with class.i did but it is calling all same class click event.How to resolve this?
http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/10345/

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-car="blue"].plus', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("car blue");
});
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-bike="blue"].plus', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("car bike");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-car="blue" class="plus">car
</a>

<a data-bike="blue" class="plus">bike
</a>
```

Comment: `.on("click").click()` is wrong. Use either one but not both : `.on("click", "a", e => {...})` or `.click( e => {...})`

Comment: Sorry..editing mistake..Now i updated

Comment: Well now it works

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best solution but you can try this way.

```
$(document).on('click','.plus').click(function(e){ 
  if($(this).data('car') == 'blue'){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("car blue");
  }  
});  

$(document).on('click','a[data-bike="blue"].plus').click(function(e){ 
  if($(this).data('bike') == 'blue')  {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("car bike");
  }
});
```

Comment: do not compare data like car blue etc...bcoz instead of dat paragraph will come

Comment: `.on("click").click()` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Go with my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zfg86Lq/5/) may be it can help you.

JS Code -

```
$(document).on('click','a[data-car="blue"].plus',function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("car blue");
});

$(document).on('click','a[data-bike="blue"].plus',function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("bike blue");
});
```